# Restart postgres server writes fatal error password authentication for user postgres in logfile

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

When i restart the postgresql server with `sudo service postgresql restart` everything works as expected.

But the logfile `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log` shows that a fatal error happened.

```
2016-12-09 11:50:26 CET LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2016-12-09 11:50:26 CET LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2016-12-09 11:50:26 CET LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections 
2016-12-09 11:50:26 CET FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2016-12-09 11:50:26 CET DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line xx: "local   all             postgres                                md5"
2016-12-09 11:50:27 CET FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I did setup the postgres superuser `postgres` with a  secure password.
I am able to login with

```
psql -U postgres
```

But the UNIX user postgres is also setup with a login shell and a password. So i locked this user by setting  `/usr/sbin/nologin` in `/etc/passwd`.
I am not able to su into the UNIX postgres user anymore but with

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

it is possible to log into the database.

Restarting the server still shows  the same error message.

In `pg_hba.conf` the method for `postgres` and `all` is set to `md5`.

I dont really understand what the server is complaining about, because the connection can be established and i am able to login.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set in pg_hba.conf user "postgres" as "peer" authentication or add into postgres $HOME directory file .pgpass with content `localhost:*:*:postgres:password`. File must have mod 600.

Comment: Excellent thanks. That removed the fatal error messages!